# Can't click Continue button on PayPal using Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automated-tests, paypal-sandbox

I've automated payment via PayPal SandBox and it used to work well until recent days. Now something has changed there and I can't click the final Continue button anymore no matter what I do. I've tried everything: regular click, Actions class, JS click, several clicks in a row. Nothing helps. The strangest thing is that when I do this in console: document.getElementById('payment-submit-btn').click(); It works and the payment completes but when I execute the same script using JavaScriptExecutor it doesn't work anymore and the button doesn't get clicked. Is there a way to solve this?[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I've mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Did you check if that element is in Iframe?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like there's an iframe and if there was then as far as I know the button wouldn't be found with this xpath: "//button[contains(@id, 'payment-submit-btn')]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this xpath to click continue button

```
**//*[contains(text(),'Continue')]**
```

OR

```
 //button[contains(text(),'Continue')]
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. The button is successfully found with both your xpath and this xpath: "//button[contains(@id, 'payment-submit-btn')]". but it doesn't get clicked using any automation means that I've tried.

Comment: did you use wait method to that button , think you need to wait and click,please use webdriver wait before click to continue button if its not let me know

Comment: Of course. The page is completely loaded and the button is present when Selenium tries to click it

Comment: did you use any thing to page load and wait ?

Comment: Yes, waiting doesn't help. I wait for all spinners to disappear before clicking and also for continue button to be clickable.

Comment: Okay, I've decided to check my waits one more time and I put Thread.sleep(30000) there before clciking a button. You're right. Something is missing because with Thread.sleep it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: dont use thread sleep use webdriver wait 
if you ok i can share customize wait method which I wrote in java ?

Comment: I know that I shouldn't use Thread.sleep(). I just use it for debugging sometimes because it's quick. Please share your method. Maybe it wiill work for me too.

Comment: private static WebElement waitForElement(By locator,int timeout)
    {
        WebElement element=new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        return element;
    }


//if you want want for id for 20 milliseconds just use below code
waitForElement(By.id(""),20);

Comment: Thanks I've had a similar wait in my code, I was waiting for visibility of continue button and it appeared not to be enough. It doesn't matter, I'll now find a way to add a necessary wait. The most important thing is that I now know why I was unable to click the button.

Answer (score 0):

For me, sometimes the PayPal pop-up open with "cookie" message and window is not full opened (continue button) is hidden.

You can achieve 100% clicking By -

1. Verify Cart button is loaded. (here we verify pop-up is loaded)
2. Accept the cookie message/button on pop-up.
3. Maximize the page.
4. Click on continue button.